# Unity use cell .jar android NFC

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, nfc

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10379 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.Company.PluginsNFC" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
      <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

      <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
          <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity.eg.NFC.UnityNFC" android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            </intent-filter>          
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />  
                <data android:mimeType="mime/type" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" /> 
        </activity>


      </application>
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

I am looking for a long time can not find where the problem is in.

Code :

```
public boolean IsUseNFC() {

        this.mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this.activity);

        if(this.mNfcAdapter == null) {
            this.activity.finish();
            return false;
        }

        if(!this.mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            this.activity.finish();
            return false;
        }

    this.mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this.activity);

    return true;
}
```

[Error] NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, you did not request the NFC permission for your app. You need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

somewhere before the `<application ... />` tag in your app mainfest.

Comment: Thank you, but just a copy and paste XML shows incomplete.
Re copy and paste XML.

Comment: @eggkouun If the uses-permission is there you should not get such an exception. Where do you call `IsUseNFC()`?

Comment: @eggkouun Also, have you checked that the generated APK actually requests the permission?